# Problemas de conexion desde el servidor AD a la computadora que esta en el dominio

Tags: dominio, activedirectory

Tengo un problema, y es que desde el servidor que tengo el AD no puedo llegar a las computadoras que estan en el dominio, a que se debe esto? Si hago ping desde el servidor a la computadora me da la ip pero no me responde ni los paquetes ni nada